# How to display particular pixels of an image in imageview in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am in a situation in which I need to display particular pixels of an Image in an ImageView.
Is there any way to do this in iPhone?Can anybody provide some Example code to do this?Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to display a small subset of your pixels.  You can get the raw pixels with [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html).

Or you can crop a photo.  Or you can mask a photo so you are left with just a small bit of your image.

What exactly do you mean by "display particular pixels"?